# Single word request: Theocracy without gods

Tags: single-word-requests

If a state is run according to a theistic religion, such as with a god as the nominal head of state, or the head of state as a nominal god, that state may be called a theocracy.

However, if no god is present in the religion running the state, for example Buddhism, or at least many versions of it, the term theocracy wouldn't apply, what with the "theo" part coming from the term for god.

So then, what term can be used to describe a state run according to a religion that does not have a god?

Answer (score 1):

[wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontheistic_religion) states on its Nontheistic_religion page :

> Nontheistic religions are traditions of thought within a religious context—some otherwise aligned with theism, others not—in which nontheism informs religious beliefs or practices.

It also [states](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theocracy) on it Theocracy page:

> Having a state religion is not sufficient enough to be a theocracy in the narrow sense of the term. Many countries have a state religion without the government directly deriving its powers from a divine authority or a religious authority directly exercising governmental powers. Since the narrow sense of the term has few instances in the modern world, the more common usage of it is the wider sense of an enforced state religion.

So I’d say ___ has a “state religion” or ___ is a “nontheist religious state”.

Comment: Nontheist religious state works, if it is a bit of a mouthful, though the  ___ has a “state religion” form does not, in my estimation, convey that the religion has a dominance in the running of the state. Heck, the UK has a state religion and is certainly far from controlled by it. Good answer.

Comment: The Kingdom does not have a state religion, madam. It has an established church. The Church of England is not a religion.

Comment: @RealYZ I understood England's "official religion" is Protestant Christianity ?!? Wikipedia says the same "While the United Kingdom's official religion is Protestant Christianity, the Church of England remains the state church of its largest constituent region, England." at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_in_the_United_Kingdom

Comment: There is no “state religion” in your own post. Official, yes, but not state. Close, but no cigar. The difference is relevant to the freedom of conscience. Besides, Wikipedia is not an authority.

Comment: @RealYZ I am not sure, to be honest, on the difference between a state and official religion. I do know that the law in the UK explicitly prohibits the monarch from being a Roman Catholic. That seems pretty hardline to me;  close to having Protestant Christianity as England’s state religion???

Comment: @k1eran. The Brits are a special case, they have no written constitution. A 300 year old law applies to the monarchy that *does not govern*. The primary function of the state is governance, and that is carried out in a completely secular way. That’s why the Church of England is not a state religion in the modern sense such as Islam is in Iran.

Comment: @RealYZ We do have the lords spiritual, 26 bishops of the C of E who are, by virtue of their religious prominence, members of the house of lords. Its not entirely in name only. Obviously no Iran, and I'd say we're better off than the US, since over here people tend to be concerned with greatly religious politicians, whilst the American politicians all seem to boast of religion.

Comment: @MegaCrow. No wonder you are better off. We are saved by God alone. You are saved by God and the U.S.

Comment: @RealYZ, I am not quite sure what your comment means. Mine was that the De facto secularism of the UK was better than the de facto religiosity of the US, and in that context I am having trouble making sense of your response. Are you crediting the US with some divinity, or is my understanding massively off the mark?

Comment: @crow. It was a joke